# Decorator on Property not called

Tags: python

Consider this decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def non_null(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Test")
        assert all(not a is None for a in args)
        return func(*args, *kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Around a property setter of a class function:

```
@non_null
    @foo.setter 
    def foo(self, argument):
        print("Setting")
        self._a = argument
```

If the non_null decorator is used, neither the function nor decorator gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `@foo.setter` have to be the outmost decorator:

```
@foo.setter 
@non_null
def foo(self, argument):
    print("Setting")
    self._a = argument
```

I could find no reference for that in the documentation, but examining the content of a class makes clear that if the property decorator in not the outmost one, you only get a simple method instead of a property.

Comment: That solved it! Btw how exactly did you discover that?

Comment: When looking what was the `foo` attribute of the class I saw it was no longer a property, which let think that the `foo.getter` had not been processed. And only the other decorator could be the cause so I tried to reverse the order...

Comment: Thank you for your help.